# How to remove whitespace from pre tag using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Consider this code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = """<pre class="code file d"><span class="kw2">import std.stdio
import core.bitop;

// parallel port address 
const uint port = 0x0c000;

void main()
{
    /*
        permission related stuff under linux
    */

    /* data */
    ubyte data = 0b_11111111;
    outp(port, data);
}
</span></pre>
"""

invalid_tags = ['span']

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

for tag in invalid_tags:
    for invalid in soup.findAll(tag):
        invalid.replaceWithChildren()

pre_tags = soup.find_all('pre')

for i in range (len(pre_tags)):
    pre_tags[i]['class'] = 'prettyprint'

output = soup.prettify(formatter=None)

output_text = output.encode('utf8', 'replace')

output_file = open('test.html', "w")
output_file.write(output_text)
output_file.close()
```

I have a simple html document. I'd like to remove some unwanted tags `<span>` in this case and change the class name of `<pre>` tag.

But if you look at the output file there is unwanted whitespace characters in the second line.

```
  <pre class="prettyprint">
   import std.stdio
import core.bitop;

// parallel port address 
const uint port = 0x0c000;

void main()
{
    /*
        permission related stuff under linux
    */

    /* data */
    ubyte data = 0b_11111111;
    outp(port, data);
}
  </pre>
```

I want to remove the unwanted space characters just before the second column and want it to be left aligned.

How can I do that? Any ideas. Thanks..

Comment: At which step is it adding the extra whitespace? In other words, if you print it out after the `replaceWithChildren` loop, is it already wrong, or does that not happen unless you print it out after the `prettyprint` loop, or even later after `prettify`, or …?

Comment: Also, why are you looping with `for i in range (len(pre_tags)):` and using `pre_tags[i]` instead of just using `for tag in pre_tags:` directly? Is this to work around some earlier bug you ran into?

Comment: @abarnert when I don't know at which step it is adding extra whitespace. I tried to find out. But I couldn't figure out. At the end it writes to file with extra whitespace. Using `for tag in pre_tags:` is more clean and nice. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean you couldn't figure it out? Just `print` if after each step, or write a file at each step, or whatever. This is the basic debugging step there is.

Comment: I mean I couldn't figure out the root of the problem. I already print it after each step. Everything looks fine. Also as you mentioned still I need to use `prettify` I think. Now I try to write real code for your pseudocode.

Comment: Actually, maybe just doing `str(tag)` for the tag contents and tag.replace_with('<pre>{}</pre>'.format(i))` for the "replace" line is all you need to turn it into real code. (Oh, and obviously `enumerate(stash)` instead of just `stash`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're calling `prettify`. All the other stuff is irrelevant. If you just print out `soup` after the span-removing loop, and again after the pre-reclassifying loop, the contents are fine; on the other hand, if you print out `soup.prettify()` right at the top, without those two loops, it's already added extra whitespace.

Why? Well, that's the whole point of `prettify`. In the docs, [Pretty-printing](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#pretty-printing) says it puts "each HTML/XML tag on its own line". And that includes `<pre>` tags.

If you want to use `prettify`, but want it to not prettify `pre` tags, you need to create and pass in a formatter that takes care of skipping the `pre` tags.

Or, alternatively, you could always do something like this (pseudocode, not real code):

```
for tag in find_all('pre'):
    replace tag contents with str(len(stash))
    stash.append(str(tag contents))
pretty = soup.prettify()
for i, tag in stash:
    pretty.replace('<pre>{}</pre>'.format(i), tag)
```

It's arguable that `prettify` should always skip `pre` tags (as it does for `CData`). See [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1095654).

Comment: But if I change `output = soup.prettify(formatter=None)` line to `output = soup` still it is adding extra whitespace?

Comment: @Erdem: That's because `encode` pretty-prints by default, so it's the same as calling `prettify`. I'm pretty sure this is explained in the same docs I linked to, only a few paragraphs away. You can use `output = str(soup)` to get the non-prettified string, and then encode that.

Comment: Thank you I realized that after writing this comment. Using `output = str(soup)` works fine for this code snippet. But my real code is a mess. If I remove `prettify` method from my real code I get a lot of errors. I know a little Python. So still I need this method I think :)

Comment: Finally I changed the output line like this `output = re.sub('<pre class="prettyprint">\s+|\s+</pre>', lambda match: match.group(0).strip(), soup.prettify())` and it works :) Thanks.